# British equivalent of 'bang for your buck'

Tags: synonyms

I'm looking for a British equivalent of 'bang for your buck'.

I thought 'power for your pound' , but I'm not sure if that works well.

Comment: more bang for your bob? more squid for your quid?

Comment: More pints for your pence.

Comment: Does the word "buck" refer exclusively to US currency (when it's referring to money at all that is)?  It's not the official name for the dollar by any means.  Do other English-speaking nations which use dollars (e.g. Canada, Australia) ever call them bucks?

Comment: @rhetorician More quid for the quid-pro-quo.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman They do in Canada.

Answer (score 4):

in Scotland they say "a bargain at twice the price", which doesn't have the punch of 'bang for the buck', but does have the advantage of lending itself to the ironic 'a bargain at half the price', which is often heard as well.

Answer (score 3):

Try [get your money's worth](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get-your-money-s-worth)

> to get good value

Also try **more bounce for the ounce** or  [worth every penny](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/worth%20every%20penny), although not that British.

> worth the entire amount that was paid for something.

Answer (score 2):

***[Value for money](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/value-for-money)***:

> - (***British***) Used in reference to something that is well worth the money spent on it:
>     *this camera is really good value for money*

(ODO)

Comment: Interesting that it’s not *value for **the** money*...

Comment: @Jim Why? It's not "bang for **the** buck" in the USA.

Comment: @TrevorD- Yes it is.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bang+for+buck%2C+bang+for+the+buck&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbang%20for%20buck%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbang%20for%20the%20buck%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Bang for the/your buck: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/more-bang-for-the-buck

Comment: @Jim  OK.  I was going from what the questioner wrote, & the expressions I've heard.  I stand corrected.

Comment: Here in India, we say "value for money" too.

Comment: @Jim bucks are countable, money is non-count.

Comment: @hobbs - Dunno what to tell ya.  But even if it’s a good value for ***the*** money [that i’d be spending] if I don’t have ***the*** money, I won’t be buying anything.